# Scaling webRTC application on Node.js

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I am working on a *webRTC* application where a *P2P* connection is established between a Customer and free agents .The agents are fetched using AJAX call in the application.I want to scale the application such that if the agents are running on any node server they are able to have a communication mechanism and update status on agent(available,busy,unavailable)can be performed.
My problem statement is that the application is running on 8040 and agentsservice is running on 8088 where the application is making ajax calls and bringing the data.What best can be done to scale the agents or any idea about how to scale the application.

I followed https://github.com/rajaraodv/redispubsub using Redis pub/sub but my problem is not resolved as the agents are being updated , fetched on another node using ajax calls .

Answer (score 0):

You didnt gave enough info... but to scale your nodejs app you need a centeral place which will hold all the info that needed and than can scale redis can scale easily, youc can try socket.io etc..
now after you have your cluster of redis for example you need to make all your node.js to communicate with the redis server that way all you nodes server will have access to same info, now its up to you to send to right info to right clients

Answer (score 0):

**Message Bus approach:**

Ajax call will send to one of the nodejs servers. If the message doesn't find its destination in that server, it will be sent to the next one, and so one. So signaling server must distribute the received message to all the other nodes in the cluster by establishing a **Message Bus**